# How to return this result object format list in javascript or angular way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a question about for loop in javascript or use angular way to output the result object list.

i have a object list as below

```
var alist = [];
    alist = [
        { 'code': 1000, 'type': 'C', 'a': 4, 'b': null, 'c': null },
        { 'code': 1000, 'type': 'C', 'a': null, 'b': null, 'c': 6 },
        { 'code': 1500, 'type': 'O', 'a': null, 'b': null, 'c': 8 },
        { 'code': 1500, 'type': 'O', 'a': null, 'b': 8, 'c': null },
        { 'code': 1000, 'type': 'O', 'a': 7, 'b': null, 'c': null },
        { 'code': 1000, 'type': 'C', 'a': null, 'b': 7, 'c': null },
        { 'code': 2000, 'type': 'C', 'a': 4, 'b': null, 'c': null },
        { 'code': 2000, 'type': 'C', 'a': null, 'b': 6, 'c': 12 },
        { 'code': 3000, 'type': 'C', 'a': 1, 'b': null, 'c': 12 },
        { 'code': 3000, 'type': 'C', 'a': null, 'b': 6, 'c': null }
    ];
```

i want the result is combine same code + same type and combine a, b, c value.
this is a result as below i want.

```
var resultList = [];
    resultList = [
        { 'code': 1000, 'type': 'C', 'a': 4, 'b': 7, 'c': 6 },
        { 'code': 1500, 'type': 'O', 'a': null, 'b': 8, 'c': 8 },
        { 'code': 1000, 'type': 'O', 'a': 7, 'b': null, 'c': null },
        { 'code': 2000, 'type': 'C', 'a': 4, 'b': 6, 'c': 12 },
        { 'code': 3000, 'type': 'C', 'a': 1, 'b': 6, 'c': 12 },
    ];
```

Keypoint :

1. code is Dynamic, not hard code for 1000, 1500, 2000.
2. one code just bind one type, so if 1000 code just include one type C.

Is possible to output this result ?

I tried in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52e84dum/1/), but i still not output the resultList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change your data in pure javascript you can use `reduce()` like this.

```js
var alist = [
  { 'code': 1000, 'type': 'C', 'a': 4, 'b': null, 'c': null },
  { 'code': 1000, 'type': 'C', 'a': null, 'b': null, 'c': 6 },
  { 'code': 1500, 'type': 'O', 'a': null, 'b': null, 'c': 8 },
  { 'code': 1500, 'type': 'O', 'a': null, 'b': 8, 'c': null },
  { 'code': 1000, 'type': 'O', 'a': 7, 'b': null, 'c': null },
  { 'code': 1000, 'type': 'C', 'a': null, 'b': 7, 'c': null },
  { 'code': 2000, 'type': 'C', 'a': 4, 'b': null, 'c': null },
  { 'code': 2000, 'type': 'C', 'a': null, 'b': 6, 'c': 12 },
  { 'code': 3000, 'type': 'C', 'a': 1, 'b': null, 'c': 12 },
  { 'code': 3000, 'type': 'C', 'a': null, 'b': 6, 'c': null }
];

var obj = {}
var result = alist.reduce(function(r, e) {
  var key = e.code + '|' + e.type;
  if (!obj[key]) {
    obj[key] = e;
    r.push(obj[key]);
  } else {
    Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach(function(el) {
      if (obj[key][el] == null) obj[key][el] = e[el];
    })
  }
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, this way is suitable for me !

Answer (score 2):

You could use some helper arrays for the key and the parameters to collect and an object to group.

```js
var data = [{ code: 1000, type: 'C', a: 4, b: null, c: null }, { code: 1000, type: 'C', a: null, b: null, c: 6 }, { code: 1500, 'type': 'O', a: null, b: null, c: 8 }, { code: 1500, type: 'O', a: null, b: 8, c: null }, { code: 1000, type: 'O', a: 7, b: null, c: null }, { code: 1000, type: 'C', a: null, b: 7, c: null }, { code: 2000, 'type': 'C', a: 4, b: null, c: null }, { code: 2000, type: 'C', a: null, b: 6, c: 12 }, { code: 3000, type: 'C', a: 1, b: null, c: 12 }, { 'code': 3000, type: 'C', a: null, b: 6, c: null }],
    keys = ['code', 'type'],
    values = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var key = keys.map(function (k) { return a[k]; }).join('|');
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = {};
        keys.forEach(function (k) { this[k] = a[k]; }, this[key]);
        values.forEach(function (k) { this[k] = null; }, this[key]);
        grouped.push(this[key]);
    }
    values.forEach(function (k) {
        if (a[k] !== null) {
            this[k] = (this[k] || 0) + a[k];
        }
    }, this[key]);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) it could be solved as follows:

```
(function (alist) {
    function mergeObjs(a, b) {
        return _.mergeWith(a, b, function (a, b, key) {
            if (['a', 'b', 'c'].indexOf(key) !== -1) {
                return _.isNull(a) && _.isNull(b) ? null : (a || 0) + (b || 0);
            }
        });
    }

    var res = _.reduce(_.groupBy(alist, 'code'), function (memo, groupedByCode) {
        return _.concat(memo, _.map(_.groupBy(groupedByCode, 'type'), function (groupedByType) {
            return _.reduce(_.tail(groupedByType), mergeObjs, _.head(groupedByType));
        }));
    }, []);

    console.log(res);
})([
    {'code': 1000, 'type': 'C', 'a': 4, 'b': null, 'c': null},
    {'code': 1000, 'type': 'C', 'a': null, 'b': null, 'c': 6},
    {'code': 1500, 'type': 'O', 'a': null, 'b': null, 'c': 8},
    {'code': 1500, 'type': 'O', 'a': null, 'b': 8, 'c': null},
    {'code': 1000, 'type': 'O', 'a': 7, 'b': null, 'c': null},
    {'code': 1000, 'type': 'C', 'a': null, 'b': 7, 'c': null},
    {'code': 2000, 'type': 'C', 'a': 4, 'b': null, 'c': null},
    {'code': 2000, 'type': 'C', 'a': null, 'b': 6, 'c': 12},
    {'code': 3000, 'type': 'C', 'a': 1, 'b': null, 'c': 12},
    {'code': 3000, 'type': 'C', 'a': null, 'b': 6, 'c': null}
]);
```

1. Group by code
2. For each code, group by type
3. For each type, merge the objects adjusting the value of the keys according to the requisites.

Though it's not as quick as other implementations, it's more declarative and gives you a hint of what's happening. Lodash is great for this kind of things, I highly recommend it. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0aqrguaa/). Hope it helps.